# Outbound call and retrieve user input without spinning up server

Tags: python, java, twilio

I started looking at Twilio and my goal is to:

1. Make a call
2. Ask user for digit input
3. Retrieve that digit

Steps 1 and 2 were fairly easy to do but it looks like for step 3 I need to spin up a **PUBLIC** server that will actually have logic to ingest that digit and do the rest of the logic and provide that public URL to call resource.

Question: Is there a way to save that digit **without** a creating a new public server and just retrieve it via existing Twilio API, similar to recordings? Due to some org restrictions, public server might not be possible. Maybe there is an easier solution than Twilio all together?

Comment: Is Twilio Studio not an option? It is all serverless, and can be used with Twilio Functions to handle everything for you, without reaching out to your edge. You could use a tool like Twilio Sync or Airtable to store results if you need to access them later.